# How to store Currency in limits in currency field

Tags: workflow, validation-rule, fields, currency

I have a requirement where I need to store values in currency field as $2,00,000/$3,00,000. Basically, that field will be used to denote limits. I cannot do that using a currency field. WHen I tried to do that using text field, I am not recieving $ symbol(which is mandatory for both upper and lower limits) as the data is bulk uploaded using Data loader. Can anyone please help me with this requirement.

Thank you in advance.
Sastri

Comment: Would you like to show as $2,00,000/$3,00,000?

Comment: yes...I need to get '/' in between both values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible using native currency field. Text field is your option here.

But you can use Trigger+ Text field to easily achieve same format. Just check in your trigger if field is not null then add currency sign with that.

Or create two separate fields to store high and low amount and then use formula field to combine them into single field.